# Implied git clone in operating instructions?

Tags: python, git, github

I have found several installation instructions from Github that appear to have an implied step where I git clone the files. I usually do this but I wonder why it's not stated explicitly. Am I doing something wrong? Here's an example from https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn:

```
virtualenv .env                  # Create the virtual environment
source .env/bin/activate         # Activate the virtual environment
pip install -r requirements.txt  # Install Python dependencies
# Work for a while ...
deactivate                       # Exit the virtual environment
```

Obviously, trying to pip install from requirements.txt doesn't do anything if I just activate a virtual environment and try to run it. I assume there's an implied `git clone https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn` step before the `pip install...` part, but I've seen in missing in so many installation instructions I'm starting to wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: Usually `.env` is created inside the project directory, so, you will first do `git clone ...` then `cd torch-rnn` then all the env setup you have mentioned inside this `torch-rnn` directory created by `git clone`.

Comment: Of course you need to somehow fetch the code to your computer before you can do anything with it. You can either clone the repository or download the code as zip.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir, OK, so you're saying it's really more of an implied first step. I guess that makes more sense than putting it in the middle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the README.md just describes how to install the files you got. Where or how you got them, whether you downloaded a ZIP, or git cloned them or typed them in with an electric typewriter is unimportant. GitHub just happens to show the README.md files content on the repository start page, but that does not mean it is exclusively shown there, but can alos be read in a local copy. So getting the sourcecode is simply out of the focus of the description. It just describes how to install the files you got in some way.